# Java Object Reference Tasks

Tags: java, object, methods

I need help to figure out a method on how to add elements to my array list. Once added i would like to have it show true or false if the element was added previously, if not then have it show true as in successfully added new Disc. This is a portion of my code so far.

```
public class MediaArchive 
{
private String name ;
private String owner ;
private ArrayList<Disc> list;

//Constructor
public MedieArkiv(String name, String owner) {
    this.name = name;
    this.owner = name;
    list = new ArrayList<Disc>();
}

//Method for adding a new "Disc" to the ArrayList.
public void addDisc(Disc newDisc) { 
    list.add(newDisc);
}
```

So my question is, how do i make a method that can add "new Discs" to my array list? And save them as parameters so the list knows if they are added or not by using ture or false to show it. 
Sidenote: I am learning this through BlueJ, and am still very fresh at the language.

Comment: list.add already returns true or false...just use that to return from addDisc to show the result

Comment: simply write a method with `List<Disc>` as parameter and additionally `String name` and `String owner` as parameter. simply call `return list.add(new Disc(name,owner));` in the method.

Comment: Override `equals` and `hashCode` in `Disc`, and then add items to a `LinkedHashSet` instead of an `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to get a list of unique `Disc` values, you should first override the `equals` and `hashCode` methods of `Disc`. This allows you to determine whether two different instances of `Disc` should be considered to have equal values.

Then, replace `ArrayList` with `LinkedHashSet`: `LinkedHashSet` is an implementation of `Set` (which, by contract, forbids duplicate values) but that also preserves insertion order - so it's a bit like a `List` without duplicates.

Now `LinkedHashSet.add(Disc)` would return `true` if the element is "new", and `false` if it was already present.

Comment: Think i found some answer in this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Implementing `Collection.add`, `List.add` returns:

> `true` if this collection changed as a result of the call

... (see [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add(E))).

Note that as mentioned by [Andy Turner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3788176/andy-turner) this will always return `true` for `ArrayList` (if an `Exception` is not being thrown by `add`).

You could also have a `Set` instead, and implement `equals` and `hashCode` in your `Disc` class, in case your check is required to ensure no duplicates are being added.

The `Set.add` method returns:

> `true` if this set did not already contain the specified element

... (see [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add(E))).

Comment: The return value of `List.add` isn't very much use by itself - it [*always* returns `true`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add(E)). You'd have to do a `contains` check first, and if you're doing that, you may as well just use a `Set`.

Comment: @AndyTurner actually that's kind of a mystery to me. The API states "if this collection changed as a result of the call", but I can't fathom a situation where it would return `false` instead of throwing exception. Bad class casts, non-writeable lists, etc. all throw exception. Seems like the "*always* return `true` rule is probably right for `ArrayList`, but the promise for any class derived from `List` enforces the above. TLDR you're right.

Comment: that's a general specification for `Collection`; `Set.add` is one example of a case where it might return false legitimately. `List.add` leaves no "if..." in the documentation: it just returns `true`.

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList` has `Contains` method, you need to pass on the argument so, that it will return true if the value is already added else it will return false.

In your case

```
if(list.contains(newDisc))   
{    
//Element already added
}   
else
{
list.add(newDisc);
}
```